# What does "ceramics tour" mean?

Tags: jumanji, jumanji-the-next-level

In *Jumanji: The Next Level* (2019), Milo tells Eddie:

> Milo: You know, Gladys and I took a road trip before she passed. We went on a **ceramics tour** through the Southwest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many (some) people find the idea of touring potteries and ceramics villages to be an appealing way to spend a few days. This, for example, is a [Ceramics Tour of Japan](https://www.insidejapantours.com/japan-small-group-tours/i-sgtpc/specialist-group-tour--pottery-and-ceramics/) where you'll meet potters, see a working pottery, visit a pottery fair and attend a pottery museum.

One would imagine that a ceramics tour of the American Southwest would encompass a range of pottery activities like visiting the [Arizona State Museum Pottery Wing](https://statemuseum.arizona.edu/exhibits/pottery-project) and a trip to the [Old Pueblo Archaeology Centre](https://www.oldpueblo.org/programs/tours/) to see traditional 'indigenous peoples' pottery, etc etc.

Note that this is the sort of thing that would largely appeal to someone who's retired. The line (along with the non-modern name "Gladys") is intended to highlight Milo's advanced age.

Answer (score 1):

They probably visited various Pueblos; Indian pottery is very collectable. They're mostly in New Mexico - San Ildefonso and Acoma, for example, and Mata Ortiz in Mexico is quite famous for pottery.

It's gorgeous stuff and often pricy.